# Network Error on calling API in React Native from few specific Android devices

Tags: android, react-native, api, react-redux

We've integrated a very simple test apk that calls a HTTPS API running on IIS into a react native application. The issue is it throws "Network Error" when trying to make API calls from Motorola C Plus phone running Android 7 & Samsung Galaxy J2.

Sample Code

```
 var dataToSend = {
      Name: name,
      Email: userEmail,
      Password: password,
      Mobile: mobile,
    };

try {
  alert('Entered inside of try block');
  const userRes = await axios.post(
    'https://api.in/api/Account/CustomerRegistration',
    dataToSend,
  );
  
//Code does not display this alert
      alert('after axios request');
      alert(JSON.stringify(userRes.data));
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error); // request failed with status code 400
      console.log('error', error);
    }
```

The app runs well on localhost as well as other android phones. Have tested SSL certificate and it looks okay. Completely clueless regarding the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Would be happy to share code if required.

Comment: Anything other than "Network Error" in the logcat?

Comment: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` add this line in android manifest.xml under application like this `<application .... android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: @DarShan No, itjust goes into the catch block when calling API throwing the network error message

Comment: And what is the exception in the catch block? Can you share that?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf its already there. P+You can see here - http://prntscr.com/22lg7i9

Comment: @DarShan updated question with code